# Komodo Edit: file save command disabled

Tags: text-editors, web-development, komodo-edit

In Komodo Edit, save button seems to always remain disabled after I make changes to any file. What could be the cause? How do I make the option enabled and save a file?

[image]

The file is local, not read-only, and can be saved normally from any other editor. This is a fresh install of Komodo Edit, and I did not make config changes (except for theme). The file is not part of a project, just opened from the file system.

There seem to be errors in the "Notification" panel, does this prevent saving? If so, how do I turn the checking off?